# syntax construction of a sequence with certain value limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

Please, I need some help to understand the given task since I am not yet used to math syntax.

The problem is

"Construct a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset [0, \infty)$ such $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n) = 1$$"

There's a given function $f(x) = doesnotmatter$ in the same exercise.

I totally understand what a sequence is and what is meant by the value limit of a sequence or a function, that is. But what is exactly meant by $f(x_n)$?

Do I have to construct a sequence whose limit value works as element $x$ in such way that $f(x)=1$?

Or do they just want me to write $x_n=\frac 1n+1$ ? But this would be $$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = 1,$$ wouldn't it?

I cannot get the connection between the given $f$ and the wanted sequence.

Comment: if you plug every $x_n$ into the function $f$ you get the sequence $(f(x_n))$

Comment: Don't be so rash as to assume something "doesnotmatter". It does. Also, you do not seem to understand sequences and limits; asking for the limit of $f(x_n)$ as $n→∞$ literally means asking for the limit of $f(x_0),f(x_1),f(x_2),\cdots$, so of course $f$ matters.